# pass array to jquery for ajax processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have form elements:

```
<tr><td>Number</td><td><input type='text' name='number[]' id='number[]'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Number</td><td><input type='text' name='number[]' id='number[]'></td></tr>
```

I want to pass the values of this array to jquery for ajax processing.

jquery doesnt like $('#numbers[]') as an id.

I have also tried

```
for (a = 0;$a<5;$a++)
{
 <tr><td>Number</td><td><input type='text' name='number[$a]' id='number[$a]'></td></tr>
}
```

but that doesnt work either.

```
 alert($(#'numbers['+i+']').val();
```

fails as well...

Comment: HTML `id` attributes should be unique for entire document.

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are special characters in jQuery selectors. You need to escape them:

```
$('#numbers\\['+i+'\\]')
```

Also, your second solution is the correct one, since element `id`s must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use brackets when you try to retrieve the data and serialize the field.

```
$('#numbers').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, this was duplicated in SO 300 times, found the answer in that I should use the

```
  $('input[name="number[]"]').each(function()
```